# Can not access endpoint URL in Springboot Rest web project

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web

I've Initialized a SpringBoot Rest in eclipse and made it a Dynamic Web project. A 3-tire principle has been followed and endpoint URLs declared in controller classes. The project deploys fine but once I try to access an endpoint that returns a 404-error. Please refer to the example below.
Used Compiler - Maven and Server - apache tomcat 9.0

MainClass.java

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class PmsAdvanced extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements 
   WebMvcConfigurer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PmsAdvanced.class, args);
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("/index.jsp");
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}
```

}

Sample Controller class

```
@RestController
@EnableWebMvc
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class PmsAdvancedController implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@PostMapping("/PMS")
public String sayHello(@RequestParam(value = "myName", defaultValue = "divi") String name) {
    return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
}

@GetMapping("/PMSA")
public String sayAge(@RequestParam(value = "age", defaultValue = "100") String age) {
    return String.format("I'm %s!", age);
}}
```

URL I've been trying to access - http://localhost:8081/pms_advance_be/test/PMSA
[image]

Comment: Please show the URL you calling (how it looks like)

Comment: Also how do you start deploy your app (as you say Tomcat I guess you are not running the main in the Spring Boot app)

Comment: @Dumbo - updated the content, sir. TIA

Comment: @derkoe - I use eclipse IDE configurations to deploy and run the project, sir. TIA

Comment: Seems like your app is not deployed or did not start properly in Tomcat - check the server logs (if you are using an external Tomcat)

Comment: @derkoe - I called the index.jsp (http://localhost:8081/pms_advance_be/index.jsp)  and that works fine. Already checked the server logs there are no errors and server is deploying

Comment: Try adding "extends SpringBootServletInitializer" to your PmsAdvanced class

Comment: @Zand did adding the SpringBootServletInitializer work?

Comment: @derkoe nope still the same

Comment: @Zand is `pms_advance_be` defined in example in `application.properties` file? Example: `server.servlet.context-path=/pms_advance_be`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you annotate something as `@Configuration` then you are telling spring that the class is a source of `@Beans`. You should therefore not have `@RequestMapping`/`@RestController`/`@GetMapping` inside the same class. Separate the relevant parts for those items out into another class.

I'm also pretty sure for the set up you have you don't need to repeatedly add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and probably only need it (if at all) alongside the root `@SpringBootApplication` annotation (possibly alongside any `@SpringBootTest` as well but don't quote me on this). If you get rid of them and read any exceptions you get back, you should be in a better position to get this working.

In MVC style apps (regardless of language) the typical naming convention is that all requests are handled by classes named "BlahBlah...**Controller**", handle incoming HTTP requests.

So in summary, to get this working, I'd start with:

1. remove all lines starting/equal to `@EnableAutoConfiguration`
2. rename `PmsAdvancedController` to `PmsAdvancedConfiguration` and keep method `addViewControllers` within it only.
3. remove `@RestController` & `@RequestMapping("/test")` from `PmsAdvancedConfiguration`
4. create a new class `PmsAdvanceController` and add to it the annotations `@RequestMapping("/test")` methods marked `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping`
5. `@RestController` combines `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` - it is not necessary. Delete.
6. I can't see what you're attempting to do with the `WebMvcConfigurer` but I am assuming you're following some sort of example judging by the "Hello Worldiness" of it... Looking at other examples online and the documentation it should work with the following two annotations: `@EnableWebMvc` and `@Configuration` all other annotations can be removed.

EDIT:

If you drop the below into a single Java file and run the `main` method it works:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PmsAdvanced extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PmsAdvanced.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
class PmsAdvancedConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer  {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("/index.jsp");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
class PmsAdvancedController {

    @PostMapping("/PMS")
    public String sayHello(@RequestParam(value = "myName", defaultValue = "divi") String name) {
        return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
    }

    @GetMapping("/PMSA")
    public String sayAge(@RequestParam(value = "age", defaultValue = "100") String age) {
        return String.format("I'm %s!", age);
    }
}
```

TESTING:

```sh
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/test/PMSA?age=30
```

Or visit in browser: `http://localhost:8080/test/PMSA?age=30`

Output:

```sh
I'm 30!
```

Note: I'm not actually 30.

Comment: I guess there are some good hints in your post but it does not answer the question asked.

Comment: True enough - I saw misconfigured/redundant code and went straight to fixing it! I'd suggest also checking you've got the right URL path. The path looks (on the face of it) to be more along the lines of `GET http://host:port/test/PMSA` but the path in use is: `GET http://host:port/pms_advance_be/test/PMSA` If OP can confirm and let us know what the result is that would be helpful

Comment: thanks for your time but even after configuring as you mentioned the problem still remains @RobEvans

Comment: are you able to provide more details... updated code, exception(s) your getting, stack trace too, any other relevant parts of code/config you're trying. I will try getting it working my end which I have not done yet